# Why do we even have $\subseteq$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, soft-question

In my years studying math, there have been various ways in which my instructors and authors have used the symbol to indicate "subset"-hood. From some people, I have been told that "$\subseteq$" signifies "a subset, but not necessarily a proper subset, i.e. it could be the whole superset" and that "$\subset$" indicates "proper subset, i.e. not the whole superset."

Meanwhile, others insist upon scrapping the "$\subseteq$" entirely, insisting that "$\subset$" is more generalizable than "$\subseteq$" as it stipulates less in its definition. And then there are others who strictly insist upon using $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$, which I personally find to be the most distasteful option.

So why do we even have a symbol for subsethood that includes non-proper subsets? In other words, why even bother with the $\subseteq$ symbol when $\subset$ is more generalizable anyway?

For example, most understand the rudimentary fact that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ implies $A = B$. But this statement is also satisfied by alternatively positing $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$ implies $A=B$.

Perhaps there is something I am missing, but I claim that $\subset$ suffices for all uses. I suppose my question might be worded in this way: do there exist situations in which $\subset$ alone is not sufficient to illustrate a theorem or proposition?

Comment: This also feels like you're asking why $\leq$ exists.

Comment: $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$ is _impossible_; it doesn't imply that $A=B$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki well it depends on how you're using $\subset$. The entire point of this post is to illustrate that there is discrepancy in how subsethood is signified. How are you using it?

Comment: My definition of $\subset$ is as follows: $A \subset B \iff \forall \, a \in A, a \in B$

Comment: Also, I would argue that $\subseteq$ stipulates less in _its_ definition than $\subset$ does; 'proper' carries a lot of weight there. $A\subseteq B$ somewhat more formally defined says that $x\in A\implies x\in B$; $A\subset B$ carries the additional clause that $A\neq B$.

Comment: Emily: Then you are using what's generally written as $\subseteq$. $\subset$ canonically implies proper subset.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki perhaps I have been hanging out with lazy mathematicians too much then!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I have seen texts where $\subset$ denotes not-necessarily-proper subset. An example is Halmos - Naive Set Theory.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "more generalizable".

Comment: @EricWofsey If we define $\subset$ as $A \subset B \iff \forall \, a \in A, a \in B$, then we have all the tools we need. If $A = B$, then $A \subset B$. If $A \neq B$ but every $a \in A$ is also in $B$, then once again $A \subset B$. Defining $\subset$ in this way, I see no use for the $\subseteq$ symbol.

Comment: Yes, no one who defines $\subset$ in that way also uses $\subseteq$.  But not everyone defines $\subset$ in that way.

Comment: Well of course you don't *need* to use symbols for both of them.  You don't even need a symbol for either of them: you could just always write "for all $a\in A$, $a\in B$" instead.

Comment: Your question is essentially about notational conventions. The comments suggest this should be made (more) explicit perhaps?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With $\subset$, a reader might not be immediately able to tell if it is referring to a not-necessarily-proper subset (i.e., $\subseteq$) or a proper subset (i.e., $\subsetneq$). After all, different authors use $\subset$ differently.

On the other hand, the notations $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ only have one meaning, so these notations immediately remove any ambiguity.